# Select multiple sheets for printing at once

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to print several Sheets in a file in one print job.

The Sheets are created dynamically; their names and the number of sheets differ each time, but I know that I want to print all sheets in the workbook apart from *Keep1* and *Keep2* (in real 7 sheets).

I want to print all sheets in one job as there could be many sheets, and this would mean a long wait and lots of print job pop-ups.

I thought of creating a selection of the sheets and then order to print.

```vb
Sub printtest()

Dim arr As Variant, sht As Worksheet

arr = Array("Keep1", "Keep2")

Application.DisplayAlerts = False

For Each sht In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    If Not UBound(Filter(arr, sht.Name, True, vbtruecompare)) >= 0 Then
        With sht.PageSetup
            .Zoom = False
            .FitToPagesWide = 1
        End With
        sht.Select False
    End If
Next sht

SelectedSheets.PrintOut

Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

I run into the following:

1. `sht.Select False` adds up each Sheet meeting the conditions to the current selection, but since the button is on active sheet *Keep1* this sheet is part of the selection (and should not be):
   [image]
2. The `.FitToPagesWide = 1` is performed for each Sheet in the selection, but `.FitToPagesTall` is also set to 1. I want to keep this as `Automatic`.
3. I don't know how to reference the selection in my print job.
   I tried:

- `sht.PrintOut` which results in

> Run-time error 91 (Object variable or With block variable not set).

- `SelectedSheets.PrintOut` which results in

> Run-time error 424 (Object required).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Print Multiple Worksheets

- You rarely need to select anything which is shown in the following code.
- It writes the worksheet names to the keys of a dictionary, which are actually an array, and uses this array (the keys) to reference the worksheets to be printed.

```vb
Sub PrintTest()
    
    Dim Exceptions() As Variant: Exceptions = Array("Keep1", "Keep2")

    Dim dict As Object: Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        If IsError(Application.Match(ws.Name, Exceptions, 0)) Then
            With ws.PageSetup
                .Zoom = False
                .FitToPagesWide = 1
                .FitToPagesTall = 2
            End With
            dict.Add ws.Name, Empty
        End If
    Next ws
    
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(dict.Keys).PrintOut
    
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

Comment: This is way better than my attempt. I was unaware of `keys` which means like 'each value from the scripting directory", correct? Also learned that setting the `.FitPagesTall to a large number (99 for example) is equivalent to Automatic. Thanks a lot!

Comment: You could think of a dictionary as two columns (since it contains two 1D zero-based arrays, two rows would be more accurate). The left column is the keys, the right column is the items. Both return a 1D zero-based array. In this particular case, `dict.Keys` returns an array of the worksheet names while `dict.Items` would return a same-sized array with `Empties` in it. To reference several sheets, you need an array of their names so that's one convenience of the dictionary. The other is that you don't need to know the number of items you're going to add to it, which is needed with arrays.

Answer (score 2):

You could try to make a string with only the worksheet names you want, excluding `Keep1` and `Keep2`. Then take that string into an unidimensional array and use that array as your selection of worksheets:

```
Dim wk As Worksheet
Dim StringWk As String
Dim ArrayWk As Variant

'string of wk names
For Each wk In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    If wk.Name <> "Keep1" And wk.Name <> "Keep2" Then StringWk = StringWk & wk.Name & "|"
Next wk

StringWk = Left(StringWk, Len(StringWk) - 1) 'clean last | delimiter in string

ArrayWk = Split(StringWk, "|")

Sheets(ArrayWk).Select

'code to print to pdf or whatever
'
'
'
'
'

Sheets("Keep1").Select 'deactivate selection


Erase ArrayWk
```

To create the array we use SPLIT:

> [Split
> function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/split-function)

Comment: That's a way to tackle point 1. I also thought of activating the sheets in the same way I created the selection. Then performing the selection false. That way the selection is correct, but I still don't know how to reference to the selected sheets as a print job